# Retrieve choosen value of a ttk.combobox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, get, ttk

I am creating a user interface where there is a first window that ask the user to choose a parameter within a list of choices. Here is an MWE :

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

Port=''
root = Tk()

PortCOM = ttk.Combobox(root, values=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
PortCOM.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",Port)
PortCOM.pack ()

root.mainloop()

print(Port)
```

So i already tried that but also :

```py
Port = PortCOM.get
Port = PortCOM.cget
```

With that last try, i get that error message :

```
<bound method Misc.cget of <tkinter.ttk.Combobox object .!combobox>>
```

For example, if the user choose the value '4' in my list of values, i want it to be stored in the variable 'Port'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you don't want extra button you can just do this

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

Port=''
root = Tk()

def set_port(_):
    global Port
    Port = PortCOM.get()
    print(Port)

PortCOM = ttk.Combobox(root, values=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
PortCOM.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", set_port)
PortCOM.pack ()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No problem. If you want more info read about event handling in tkinter

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a bind to track the variable. You can do this with a StringVar.
That said you cannot just call `Port = PortCOM.get` in the global as the code is initiated and expect to get anything. 1st issue with that the correct syntax is `Port = PortCOM.get()` with parenthesis. 2nd you are calling `get()` at init and thus the only possible value would be an empty string if not an error.

The next issue I see is the `bind()` this is not doing what you think it is doing. The bind is used to call a function not to update a variable directly.

The correct use of `Combobox` is to use a `textvariable` with an `IntVar()` or `StringVar()` depending on the values and then use `get()` on that var when you need it in a function.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


root = Tk()

textVar = StringVar(root)
textVar.set('')
PortCOM = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=textVar, values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
PortCOM.pack()


def print_value():
    print(textVar.get())


Button(root, text='Print Value', command=print_value).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you really want to use `bind()` for some reason like to have the selection immediately do something when selected then try this instead.

Make sure the bind call is after the function used to do something with your combobox.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


root = Tk()

textVar = StringVar(root)
textVar.set('')
PortCOM = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=textVar, values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
PortCOM.pack()

# Note the _ in the argument section of the function.
# A bind will send an event to the function selected unless you use a lambda.
# so to deal with events we don't care about we have a few options.
# We can use an underscore to just except any argument and do nothing with it.
# We could also do event=None but typically I only use that when a function might use the event variable but not always.
def print_value(_): 
    print(textVar.get())
    print(PortCOM.get())


PortCOM.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", print_value)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you are writing whole answer you should explain why did you use (_) when defining print_value

Answer (score 0):

Look at this OO example to use all the power of the combo ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Main(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        self.values = ('Apple','Banana','Orange','Grapes','Watermelon','Plum','Strawberries','Pear')

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        f = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Label(f, text = "Combobox").pack()
        self.cbCombo = ttk.Combobox(f,state='readonly',values=self.values)
        self.cbCombo.pack()

        w = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Button(w, text="Callback", command=self.on_callback).pack()
        ttk.Button(w, text="Reset", command=self.on_reset).pack()
        ttk.Button(w, text="Set", command=self.on_set).pack()
        ttk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def on_callback(self,):

        if self.cbCombo.current() != -1:
            msg = "You have selected:\n{0}".format(self.cbCombo.get())
        else:
            msg = "You did not select anything"

        messagebox.showinfo(self.parent.title(), msg)


    def on_reset(self):
        self.cbCombo.set('')

    def on_set(self):
        self.cbCombo.current(0)

    def on_close(self):
        self.parent.on_exit()

class App(tk.Tk):
    """Start here"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)

        self.set_title()
        self.set_style()

        frame = Main(self,)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def set_style(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        #('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
        self.style.theme_use("clam")


    def set_title(self):
        s = "{0}".format('Simple App')
        self.title(s)

    def on_exit(self):
        """Close all"""
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Simple App", "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]